# How to have a constant error[b-a] for a range of values [1d array] in decending order that are not linear but are semi-linear?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, linear-algebra

I am trying to generate n numbers in decending order (for the purpose of decreasing order of weights) such that their sum should be 100 and more importantly the difference between anytwo numbers consecutively should be the same.

I am already using the python dirichlet random function. But anyway it does not give equally distanced weights.

Example:
The error term can be anything but it should be common number for all cases, such that it should be logical to convert from current error to the new common error.
[image: Example]

Comment: If the initial value is $x_0$ and the gap between values is $-d$ then you want $nx_0-d\frac{n(n-1)}2 =100$ so: given $d$, choose $x_0=\frac{100}{n} + \frac{d(n-1)}{2}$; or given $x_0$, choose $d=\frac{2x_0}{n-1}-\frac{200}{n(n-1)}$.  Try an example to see: e.g. with $n=5$, you could have $x_0=30$ and $d=5$ to get the values $30,25,20,15,10$

Comment: Thank you it is was what I was searching for. It would be very helpful if you could say on what basis the d should be choosen. Since if I have d = 5 and n = 7, then the last value will be in minus. Which is also undisirable. Or Kindly can you share the reference for the above?

Comment: You can make $d$ whatever you want (even negative or $0$).  If you want all your weights to be positive then you need $|d| < \frac{200}{n(n-1)}$